# Xpath query in PHP to attribute from element with specific attribute value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm truly bending my head over something that should be way to simple. I have an XML feed with 25 entries in the root. I'm already iterating them as `$entry` in PHP.

Here is an example of one entry in the xml feed:

```
<entry>
      <id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-7691515427771054332.post-4593968385603307594</id>
      <published>2014-02-10T06:33:00.000-05:00</published>
      <updated>2014-02-10T06:40:34.678-05:00</updated>
      <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="Aurin" />
      <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="fan art" />
      <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="Fred-H" />
      <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="spellslinger" />
      <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="wildstar" />
      <title type="text">Fan Art Showcase: She's gunnin' for trouble!</title>
      <content type="html">Some random content</content>
      <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.blogger.com/feeds/7691515427771054332/posts/default/4593968385603307594" />
      <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.blogger.com/feeds/7691515427771054332/posts/default/4593968385603307594" />
      <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.wildstarfans.net/2014/02/fan-art-showcase-shes-gunnin-for-trouble.html" title="Fan Art Showcase: She's gunnin' for trouble!" />
      <author>
         <name>Name Removed</name>
         <uri>URL removed</uri>
         <email>noreply@blogger.com</email>
         <gd:image rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail" width="32" height="32" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ow-dvUDbNxI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABTY/MhrybgagMv0/s512-c/photo.jpg" />
      </author>
      <media:thumbnail xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" url="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ifp6awhDJuU/UWQEUl8nhUI/AAAAAAAABss/BSZ_YYM1U38/s72-c/fan-art-header.png" height="72" width="72" />
</entry>
```

I want to get the `href` of the third link with `rel` set to `alternate`. The alternate link isn't always the third one. I know how to do this through SimpleXML, but I want to get to know xpath for this, because through simpleXML it's more complicated and with this I hope I'm one step closer to understanding complex xpath queries.

The PHP I got that makes the most sense to me is:

```
$href = $entry->xpath('link[@rel="alternate"]/@href');
```

I tried multiple queries based on the information I found, but they all resulted in nothing. Here is a list of the queries I tried:

- `$href = $entry->xpath('link[@rel="alternate"]/@href/text()');`
- `$href = $entry->xpath('link[@rel="alternate"]')->getAttributes()->href;`
- `$href = $entry->xpath('*[@rel="alternate"]'); $href = $href['href'];`

Comment: An attribute is not a `text()` node, so [`(string)$entry->xpath('link[@rel="alternate"]/@href')[0]`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WVuPQv) works for me. The `[0]` [requires php >= 5.4](http://3v4l.org/XsOha) BTW.

Comment: BTW: if `link` does not find anything... are you sure you are in an `entry` node?

Comment: I'm working with PHP 5.3. `link` returns an empty array indeed. But I can get the title through simpleXML with $entry->title. So I must be in the `entry` right?

Comment: Hm, what does `$entry[0]->query()` do?

Comment: It returns `Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::query()`. When I `print_r($entry[0])` (or without the [0]) it returns the entry: http://www.wildupdates.com/test/test.php

Comment: Erm, sorry, mixing up my `DOM` & `SimpleXML`: I meant just use you `->xpath()` query on `$entry[0]` rather then on `$entry`.

Comment: `$href = $entry[0]->xpath('link[@rel="alternate"]/@href'); print_r($href);` returns an empty array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47263/discussion-between-bob-and-wrikken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out from [the chat conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47263/discussion-between-bob-and-wrikken) from my original question I had to register the namespace. In the end I used [this website](http://www.a-basketful-of-papayas.net/2010/04/using-php-dom-with-xpath.html) and the code turned out to be like this:

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load("http://www.wildstarfans.net/feeds/posts/default");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($feed);
$xpath->registerNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//atom:entry') as $entry) {

    $href = $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:link[@rel="alternate"]/@href)', $entry);

}
```

Credits go to [ThW](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2265374/thw) and [Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358679/wrikken). Wish I could give you guys SO points for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$href = $entry->xpath('link[@rel="alternate"]');
$href = (string) $href[0]->attributes()->href;
```

Comment: The first line returns an empty array, resulting in an error for line 2: `Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object`. `*[@rel="alternate"]` does seem to work, but that's not tidy coding. What am I missing here?